# Header codification incompatibility between vbulletin and wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, vbulletin

I'm creating a new vbulletin page where wordpress it's included.

http://www.turiver.com/noticias/

vb charset: charset=ISO-8859-1"
wp charset: utf-8

Is it possible to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are the php functions utf8_encode and utf8_decode to convert between ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8.